# What is the geometrical interpretation of Abel's formula $\frac{d}{dt}W=-p(t)W$? $W$ is the Wronskian.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The Wronskian is $W(x_1,x_2)=det\begin{pmatrix}\ x_1 & x_2\\ \dot{x_1} & \dot{x_2} \end{pmatrix}=\dot{x_1}x_2-x_1\dot{x_2}$, where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are solutions of $\ddot{x}+p(t)\dot{x}+q(t)x=0$.

Abel's formula: $\frac{d}{dt}W=-p(t)W$ or $W(x_1,x_2)=Ce^{-\int p(t)dt}$.

What is the geometrical interpretation of Abel's formula?

Comment: Why do you want a geometric interpretation of Abel's formula?

Comment: It is basically the evolution of the parallelogram in phase plane generated by the two solutions $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Comment: @JackyChong That's my professor's question in class.

Comment: I have given you the solution.

Comment: @JackyChong Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you understand what I have said?

Comment: @JackyChong  $\frac{d}{dt} W$ is the rate of change of parallelogram's area created by $(x_1, \dot{x_1})$ and $(x_2, \dot{x_2})$ in phase plane. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. That is correct. For simplicity, you should work out the case $y''+y=0$.